# Merge data depending on object and no gaps in dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got in the DB data like you can see below (additional info about dates: date in valid_from is included, date in valid_to is excluded)

| obj_number | obj_related | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | BB | 01.01.2018 | 01.01.2019 |
| AA | BB | 01.01.2019 | 31.03.2019 |
| AA | BB | 31.03.2019 |  |
| AA | CC | 01.01.2020 | 30.06.2020 |
| AA | CC | 02.07.2020 | 31.10.2020 |
| AA | CC | 31.10.2020 | 31.12.2020 |
| AA | DD | 01.01.2018 | 30.11.2020 |
| AA | DD | 30.11.2020 | 31.12.2020 |

I have to merge the data, but in a special way. It should be merged around obj_related to show the minimum valid_from and maximum valid_from/null. But if there is a GAP in dates like you can see for CC (row 4 and 5) then both records should be in the result. The best way to understand it when I show you the correct result:

| obj_number | obj_related | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | BB | 01.01.2018 |  |
| AA | CC | 01.01.2020 | 30.06.2020 |
| AA | CC | 02.07.2020 | 31.12.2020 |
| AA | DD | 01.01.2018 | 31.12.2020 |

**Oracle version**: 12.1.0.2

Could you help me to prepare an SQL query

Comment: What is your Oracle version? As in 11.2.0.4 or 12.2.0.1? If you don't know, run `select * from v$version` and see what it reports.

Comment: My version: 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: OK - please see how I edited your post. I added the Oracle version at the end. Please remember to do this (or similar) whenever you ask a question in an online forum. (Not only for Oracle - for any kind of "software" question you ask.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different solution, which should work in Oracle 10.1 and higher - using the Tabibitosan method. The problem is slightly complicated by the use of `NULL` to mark an indefinite `valid_to` date; in particular, the definition of `valid_to` in the outer query can't simply be `max(valid_to)` within each group, since that would produce the wrong answer when `valid_to` may be `null`.

Other than that, the computation that produces the `grp` column in the subquery is the main idea: it produces a different date for each "island" in the "gaps and islands" structure of the input data. This is a less known use of the Tabibitosan method; it makes this kind of query as efficient as possible since it requires only one level of analytic functions.

```
/*
with
  sample_data (...) as (...)
*/
select obj_number, obj_related, min(valid_from) as valid_from,
       max(valid_to) keep (dense_rank last order by valid_from) as valid_to
from   (
         select sd.*,
                nvl(valid_to, date '9999-12-31') - 
                  sum(nvl(valid_to, date '9999-12-31') - valid_from)
                      over (partition by obj_number, obj_related 
                            order     by valid_from) as grp
         from   sample_data sd
       )
group  by obj_number, obj_related, grp
order  by obj_number, obj_related, valid_from
;
```

The best way to try to understand how the Tabibitosan method works (in this case) is to run the subquery separately and to see what it produces.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 12.1 or higher, you can solve this easily with `match_recognize`:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='dd.mm.yyyy';

with
  sample_data (obj_number, obj_related, valid_from, valid_to) as (
    select 'AA', 'BB', to_date('01.01.2018'), to_date('01.01.2019') from dual union all
    select 'AA', 'BB', to_date('01.01.2019'), to_date('31.03.2019') from dual union all
    select 'AA', 'BB', to_date('31.03.2019'), null                  from dual union all
    select 'AA', 'CC', to_date('01.01.2020'), to_date('30.06.2020') from dual union all
    select 'AA', 'CC', to_date('02.07.2020'), to_date('31.10.2020') from dual union all
    select 'AA', 'CC', to_date('31.10.2020'), to_date('31.12.2020') from dual union all
    select 'AA', 'DD', to_date('01.01.2018'), to_date('30.11.2020') from dual union all
    select 'AA', 'DD', to_date('30.11.2020'), to_date('31.12.2020') from dual
  )
select *
from   sample_data
match_recognize(
  partition by obj_number, obj_related
  order     by valid_from
  measures  first(valid_from) as valid_from, last(valid_to) as valid_to
  pattern   ( a b* )
  define    b as valid_from = prev (valid_to)
);

OBJ_NUMBER OBJ_RELATED  VALID_FROM VALID_TO  
---------- ------------ ---------- ----------
AA         BB           01.01.2018           
AA         CC           01.01.2020 30.06.2020
AA         CC           02.07.2020 31.12.2020
AA         DD           01.01.2018 31.12.2020
```

Obviously, the `with` clause is not part of the solution (remove it and use your actual table and column names); I included it for testing.

Comment: another time someone help me with match_recognize - amazing function. I have to learn more and more about it. thank you very much !!!

Comment: @lelek - don't think of `match_recognize` as a function; think of it as a process that generates rows (similar to "join", or - even better - similar to "pivot", or "connect by", etc.). It has a lot in common with analytic functions, and also a lot in common, in a beautiful way, with regular expressions. It takes time to learn, but it is exceptionally powerful, very much worth learning.

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.

For your sample data, you can use `lag()` to see if the previous row overlaps.  If not, then the row is the start of an island.  A cumulative sum of the island starts defines all rows in the island -- which can be used for aggregation:

```
select obj_number, obj_related, min(valid_from), max(valid_to)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_valid_to >= valid_from then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by obj_number, obj_related order by valid_from) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(valid_to) over (partition by obj_number, obj_related order by valid_from) as prev_valid_to
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by obj_number, obj_related;
```

Comment: the result is not ok - for AA/BB valid_to should be null. for AA/CC we should have two records, because there is a gap in dates and your query merge all 3 records (sorry, but I don't know how can I arrange the text)              AA BB 01-JAN-18 00.00.00 31-MAR-19 00.00.00
AA CC 01-JAN-20 00.00.00 31-DEC-20 00.00.00
AA DD 01-JAN-18 00.00.00 31-DEC-20 00.00.00

Comment: There are two unrelated mistakes in this query. One is obvious: since the data uses `null` for "plus infinity", `max(valid_to)` in the outer query is incorrect, since `max` ignores `null`. The other mistake is in the `case` expression within analytic `sum` in the middle query; it should distinguish between `=` and `>`, and it doesn't. Not a helpful answer. (Besides, I showed in a different answer how the problem can be solved more efficiently with the Tabibitosan method, so this answer wouldn't be helpful even after fixing the mistakes.)