# Select and skip rows by date range with checking difference between them

Tags: sql, teradata, gaps-and-islands, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm new in Teradata and i have a small sql problem,
similar to this one below :

source table A:

```
a|b|c|  dt      |dt_f
-------------------------
1|1|5|30/01/2020|21/02/2020
1|1|2|28/02/2020|19/03/2020
1|1|2|20/03/2020|17/04/2020
1|1|2|19/04/2020|05/05/2020
1|1|2|30/06/2020|24/07/2020
1|1|2|27/07/2020|31/12/2999
```

output wanted:

```
a|b|c|    dt    |dt_f
------------------------------
1|1|5|30/01/2020|**27/02/2020**
1|1|2|28/02/2020|**19/05/2020**
1|1|2|30/06/2020|**31/12/2999**
```

Explanation:

1 --> if c is different (between current row and the next one) so dt_f of the current row = dt of the next row - 1 day , the two rows are selected

2--> if months_between(dt,dt) > 1 ( in the exmple between the row number 4 and the row number 5) so dt of  the first row selected with same id a,b and c will be df ( of row number 4) + 1 month
and the row 5 will be selected with dt_f = 31/12/2999.

I tried a lot using with recursive but i didn't get the real result, but i believe it can be solved with it.

thank's for your replies :)

Comment: If you have this problem in Teradata, why is your question tagged `oracle`? Will an Oracle solution help you? If not, please "Edit tags" (find it at the bottom of your question, click on it) and remove the misleading tag. Thank you!

Comment: Other than that - I answered essentially the same question in another thread today; the analytic solution approach (using the Tabibitosan method) should work in most database products, since most products support analytic functions. You may have to modify it to follow the Teradata SQL dialect (for example, for the difference between dates), but otherwise it should be easy to adapt. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940272/merge-data-depending-on-object-and-no-gaps-in-dates/65941207#65941207

Comment: @mathguy thanks for your reply, i saw your solution on the other question, but in my case i have huge data that i don't knwo it and i gave just an exemple, i need a dynamic query.

Comment: A "dynamic query"? I don't know what you mean by that. The term has a very clear technical meaning, which is almost certainly different from what you have in mind. What is "dynamic" in your query? Do you mean, you need a solution where the data resides in your database, not in the WITH clause? Or what?

Comment: yes i mean solution with data in database, "dynamic" i mean general, wich will work with any exmple of data.

Comment: @mathgay oops, now i understand what you mean, you answer on the other question seems to be the best start to resolve my problem, i will test it, thank you

Comment: Looking at your problem more closely, it is different from the other thread in two ways: first, both your dates are "inclusive" (that is easy to adapt from the other problem), and your date intervals (ranges) may have gaps between them, in which case you want to "keep the most recent value of `c`" (which does not have an equivalent in the problem in the other thread).

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain for each input row, which logic is applied? Recursive might be quite bad, but analytic functions should work (or maybe Teradata's equivalent to Oracle's MATCH, nPath)

Comment: @mathguy there 1 case that make me keep the recent of c: if there is only one row of a,b,c. I precise that if there is lot rows of same a,b,c --> no gap > 1 month so we keep the first row and we put dt_f = 31/12/2999, if there is a gap + 1 month between dt of the next rows so the dt_f of the first row (actual row) take dt(of the start of the gap row 4 in ex) + 1 'M' and the second row of the gap is selected (row 5 in ex) with puting dt_f = 31/12/2999 ( because the data of the group a,b,c don't see any change after c=2 if not the dt_f of the row 5 take the dt -1 day of the new row a,b,c group)

Comment: @dnoeth the data is grouped by a,b and ordre by dt. Begin with the first row if the next row have the same value of c and there is no gap between dt of any consecutive rows , so the row is selected with dt_f = 31/12/2999. If the next row have value of c different so dt_f = dt of the next row - 1 day now we move to the next row (number 2 in ex) if the next rows have the same c so and no gap so only this row is selected with dt_f =31/12/2999 if there is gap the actual row take dt ( of the fist row in wich the gap start n 4 in ex) +1 month as dt_f and the row 5 is selected with dt_f = 31/12/2999

Comment: Why is the 28/02/2020 from the 2nd row not included in the result?

Comment: @dnoeth, ZUT i made a mistake, in fact the second row in output is the second row in table A ( difference just in dt_f ) in this example, i have corrected and checked, now it's ok, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was just about returning overlapping rows, it would be really simple using Teradata's NORMALIZE extension:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt 
(a INT, b INT, c INT, dt DATE, dt_f DATE)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO vt(1, 1, 5, DATE '2020-01-30', DATE '2020-02-21');
INSERT INTO vt(1, 1, 2, DATE '2020-02-28', DATE '2020-03-19');
INSERT INTO vt(1, 1, 2, DATE '2020-03-20', DATE '2020-04-17');
INSERT INTO vt(1, 1, 2, DATE '2020-04-19', DATE '2020-05-05');
INSERT INTO vt(1, 1, 2, DATE '2020-06-30', DATE '2020-07-24');
INSERT INTO vt(1, 1, 2, DATE '2020-07-27', DATE '2999-12-31'); 

WITH cte AS 
 ( -- adjusting for gaps > 1 month
   SELECT NORMALIZE a,b,c
     ,PERIOD(dt, Add_Months(dt_f,1)) AS pd
   FROM vt
 )
SELECT a,b,c
  ,Begin(pd) AS dt
  ,Add_Months(End(pd),-1) AS dt_f
FROM cte
;
```

But your logic to adjust the end date needs Analytic Functions. This is probably the simplest query to get those overlapping periods plus additional columns, modified to match your logic:

```
WITH cte AS
 ( -- returns both start/end of an island, but in seperate rows
   SELECT 
      a,b,c
     ,dt        -- start of current island
     ,Max(dt_f) -- end of previous island (used for finding gaps)
      Over (PARTITION BY a,b,c
            ORDER BY dt
            ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding
                     AND 1 Preceding) AS prev_max_end
     ,Lag(dt)   -- to adjust end date in case of gap > 1 month
      Over (PARTITION BY a,b,c
            ORDER BY dt) AS prev_dt
   FROM vt
   QUALIFY Add_Months(prev_max_end,1) < dt -- gap found
        OR prev_max_end IS NULL            -- first row
 )
SELECT
   a,b,c
  ,dt -- start of current island

   -- next row has end of current island
  ,CASE
     WHEN Lead(c ) -- change in c column?
          Over (PARTITION BY a,b
                ORDER BY dt) <> c 
     THEN Lead(dt) -- start of next island - 1
          Over (PARTITION BY a,b
                ORDER BY dt) -1
     ELSE -- 
          Lead(Add_Months(prev_dt,1),1,DATE '2999-12-31')
          Over (PARTITION BY a,b
                ORDER BY dt)
   END
FROM cte
;
```

Comment: It works very well, i need to learn more and more about this type of problem. Thank you very much @dnoeth